# Genetics in Blade Runner 2049

Tags: blade-runner-2049

One of the peculiar bits about Blade Runner 2049 for someone with background in biology, at least from my perspective, is how genetic data and analysis is presented in the film.

It seems that many if not all humans had their genomes known (genotyped or sequenced) and stored in the DNA database. By definition, all replicants should have their genomes known as well. So, what was K doing exactly in the "DNA archive"? Namely:

- Since the genome of Rachael was known, it was a matter of searching the database for suitable matches to her potential child.
- Why and how was K comparing the sequences by eye?
- How is it possible for a male and a female human (or any other creature with genetically determined sex) to have "identical DNA"?

Any insights are welcome.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I think you have a few too many separate questions here; you should refine this down to one specific question that can, if needed, generate follow-up questions if some of these remain unanswered.  You might want to take the [tour] for a better intro on how best to use the site.

Comment: As someone who has background in IT  (and a bit of physics) I am often appalled by Hollywood Hacking or the "Cold" vacuum that freezes everything instantly. Suspend your disbelief and enjoy the show.

Comment: K is not human and can review records faster than you.  The records are on an old system due to a worldwide EM pulse destroying most data. (Blade runner is alt 1980s tech anyway).  The male and female records are identical because one is fake.  It's not clear replicants have inherited DNA - they are assembled not grown and are likely chimera DNA-wise.

Comment: Ditto what Yasskier said, for geology as well. Most geology- and paleontology-related science fiction movies ("The Core", "Volcano") are cringeworthy when they are not unintentionally funny. Though I enjoyed the scientific accuracy of "Dante's Peak" until the characters decided to walk over hardening lava. And I have very little to fault "Deep Impact" or "Supervolcano". Watch one of them instead.

Comment: OK, I think I have a satisfactory answer will post it.

Comment: Your edit doesn't really fix the main issue, which is that there are three or four distinct questions here

Comment: No, your last edit makes it worse by making this a multiple question again.

Comment: OK, I feel like there is mis-understanding on multiple fronts, I take full responsibility for that. We are leaving this as it is, thanks everyone for the input.

Answer (score 2):

The technology level in the *Blade Runner* series is different to one in our world, a bit akin to one in the *Fallout* universe: from one hand it is advanced enough to have off-world colonies, replicants and flying cars, but that doesn't guarantee that they have the data-processing capabilities similar to ones we have. Also, in 2022 there was a ["Blackout" incident](https://www.cbr.com/2022-blackout-explained-blade-runner-2049/), which has corrupted most of the data (down to personal photos), especially the genetic information used to identify replicants. All existing data might also be hard to access, even to a police officer (and especially hard to a replicant).

Comment: Thanks for your input! To the point about technology: if they have software at all, they should be able to write a program to compare strings (in this case, the genomes or SNPs appear aligned already, so it's a matter of simply comparing characters one-by-one).

Comment: @alephreish The plot point is "Joe discovers evidence in the DNA archives that someone's records have been falsified." If this were a real incident rather than a movie, he'd start by getting API credentials for the archive, then find or write a program to search the archived data, and then he'd make a sandwich while it ran. But this _is_ a movie, and **film is a visual medium** that favors obvious action paired with exaggerated, observable displays of characters' internal states. No sci-fi blockbuster is going to devote screen time to a programmer fine-tuning some data-processing script.

Comment: @Tom My comment is no longer relevant: according to the plot, the digitized data were lost and K was dealing with "raw" data which is why he could not use any software (although he intended to).